# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager setMaxTotal or setDefaultMaxPerRoute don't seem to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x

In a spring boot application, I am creating a connection pool using PoolingHttpClientConnectonManager as follows:

```
      @Bean
      public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager createCM() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pcm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);
        return pcm;
      }
```

Since I have only one route, I keep the values of setMaxTotal and setDefaultMaxPerRoute same.

The underlying httpClient configuration is as follows:

```
      @Bean
      public CloseableHttpClient createHttpClient(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pcm, RequestConfig rc) {

          CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
          .create()
          .setConnectionManager(pcm)
          .setDefaultRequestConfig(rc)
          .build();
        return httpClient;
      }
```

Now the problem is that when I stress test my application under very heavy loads to see how my connection pool would behave, I don't see the expected. 
I monitor the threads of the application using jConsole and every single time I see only 2 connection pool threads in runnable state namely https-jsse-nio-80-ClientPoller-1 and https-jsse-nio-80-ClientPoller-2.

I presume under heavy loads of the order of 1500 requests per second, it should have done it by more than 2 (default) connections in the pool. wondering what's going wrong or if my configuration is not correct.

Comment: Add specific name for your bean an then use `@Qualifier(name)` to make sure that your bean has been injected.

Comment: There is just one bean of each type. so no need of qualifier here.

Comment: Watching the NIO threads might not be the way to go since they can serve many sockets simultaneously. When your test is running, use `netstat -n` to see how many concurrent TCP connections are being maintained to your target host. (-n is faster because it doesn't have to resolve host names)

Comment: Target host is out of my domain. Its a third party service. I just want to see what happens at my end

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using http component as soap client library and I use a class implementing WebServiceGatewaySupport.
On this i do as follows:

```
httpComponentsRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
httpComponentsRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
httpComponentsRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
httpComponentsRequestFactory.setHttpClient(createHttpClient(createConnectionManager(), createRequestConfig()));
client.setMessageSender(new ClientHttpRequestMessageSender(httpComponentsRequestFactory));
```

and enabling logging to level DEBUG for org.apache.http I see now:

```
Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://host:8080][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 100]
```

so I manged to rise the default to 100 connections.